# Ubuntu 16.04 only hard shutdown instead of shutdown/suspend/hibernate

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I recently got a new PC (Acer Extensa 2520) with Linux pre-installed. I got a brick with text-environment only so I formatted and installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything works just fine but every time I close the lid, shutdown, sleep or suspend I hear the "tick" of the hard shutdown and the PC goes off. When I turn it back on, it's evident it has done a shut down as if I had long-pressed the shutdown button instead of properly suspending it.

EDIT: Indeed I'd like the computer to suspend or hibernate or whatever when I close the lid. Anything that is not shutdown or remaining on is fine. And yes, this happens both when I close the lid and when I press suspend or anything else from the menu.

Comment: I can't help you but it might increase the chance that others can if you add to you question what happens when you choose "Suspend" from the power menu and don't close the lid. You should also specifically state whether you want your laptop to be suspended or to do nothing if the lid is closed.

Comment: In your System settings Power menu is it setup to suspend on lid close or power off?